# Optaplanner hard link depot with customer

Tags: optaplanner, vehicle-routing

I have a VRPTW case where multiple delivery orders are provided. 10 depots are serving 30 customers based on time windows. Each delivery order is hardly linking depot to customer. E.g. ORDER 1 require delivery of 10 units from DEPOT 1 to CUSTOMER 1, ORDER 2 require delivery of 30 units from DEPOT 1 to CUSTOMER 2 etc..

What could be an aproach to make parametrization in XML to link CUSTOMER to DEPOT?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to do changes in the domain model, so Customer.java and Depot.java so there's an element that can be added in the xml files.
You'd also need to add a constraint rule in the vehicleRoutingScoreRules.drl

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey! That exactly what we are going to do! What is the source file responsible for parsing XML files?